# Counting characters inside of a textarea using Angular

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, form, angular-2+

I have a `textarea` and need to calculate how many characters have been typed into it.

Both of the following solutions work correctly—which would be preferable, and why? Is there an even better way to implement it?

**Option A:**

```
<textarea 
   id="descriptionEducation" 
   name="description" 
   rows="5" 
   [(ngModel)]="fruit.description"></textarea>

<div class="form-row__description">
    You have written {{ fruit.description.length }} characters
</div>
```

**Option B:**

```
<textarea 
   id="descriptionEducation" 
   name="description" 
   rows="5" 
   [ngModel]="fruit.description" #descriptionFruit></textarea>

<div class="form-row__description">
    You have written {{ descriptionFruit.value.length }} characters
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *character*? UTF-16 code unit? Unicode codepoint? Grapheme cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to declare an extra reference variable. I would suggest the first approach i.e. using `[(ngModel)]` for two-way data binding.

However, in the first approach, you must initialize the model value before using it in your template i.e. `fruit.description` should not be undefined otherwise you'll get the following TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Using the second approach, you wont get that error.

Comment: Yes! You're right! we saw the error. How do you mean with `initialize the model value`? we tried to do it but still see the same error. Would be great if you could give an example. (sorry cannot reply directly, my reputation is < 50)

Comment: @ivanasetiawan it means that `fruit.description` should be initialize e.g. if it is of type `string`, then `fruit.description = '';`

Comment: I added `public fruit: any = { description: ''};` on `.ts` file but still see the error.. What am I missing?

Comment: i dont see any erros, see this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgorb6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok that's weird.. That's how I implemented as well. This is the error I got http://oi63.tinypic.com/nboxvk.jpg

Comment: create a plunker or stackblitz demo

Comment: Ok solved it! the problem occurred because the `textarea` is inside a tab element. Therefore we need to reinitialize the model value everytime a tab button is clicked. In this case, if we use `optB` we don't need to reinitialize it everytime.

Answer (score 5):

Both are indeed completely valid. But since Angular is a databinding framework I would suggest using the two-way binding directive `[(ngModel)]` to keep things more Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Forms and will do it totally async way.

```
<textarea 
   id="descriptionEducation" 
   name="description" 
   rows="5" 
   [formControl]="textControl"></textarea>

<div class="form-row__description">
    You have written {{ descriptionLength | async }} characters
</div>
```

Inside of component

```
public textControl = new FormControl('');
public descriptionLength = new BehaviorSubject(0);
constructor(){
  this.textControl.valueChanges.subscribe((v)=> this.descriptionLength.next(v.length));
}
```

Now you can even mark you control `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and it will work